# soundcloud API - detect if a track does not exist / SC.Widget.Events.ERROR

Tags: javascript, jquery, soundcloud

Is it possible to detect if a track does not exist using the soundcloud widget?

I tried using the

```
SC.Widget.Events.ERROR
```

event to no avail.

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GregWebBandit/hKgnT/)

Comment: I'm running into the same issue also, but with tracks that were removed by users.

Comment: @juminoz  So, what i ended up doing was, detecting if the song was from a "track"or a "playlist" by reading the src attr. Of course my use case was specifically to detect whether the track was from a  track or playlist.  Im still unsure why the ERROR event does not work if just trying to detect whether a track exists.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon exact the same problem,

```
SC.Widget.Events.ERROR
```

doesn't fire if a track on soundcloud is deleted.

My workaround looks like this:

```
  var link = "https://soundcloud.com/jaytantrumdesire/tantrum-desire-get-with-it";
  var isDef = SC.get('/resolve', { url: link }, function(track) {
   return track.id;
  });
  if (isDef != undefined) {
    // function to run when track exists
  } else if (isDef == undefined) {
    // function to run when track deleted/not available
  }
```

Since i work with direct links I check if the direct link has an ID, if it has, the track is available, if doesnt't, the track is not available.

If you are working with the track IDs I guess you could check if the ID has a track title:

```
  var trackid = "32260824";
  var isDef = SC.get('/tracks/' + trackid, function(track) {
    return track.title; 
  });
```

To call these functions you must create an app on soundcloud to get a ClientID to use the soundcloud JavaScript SDK. An introduction on how to use it can be found on [Soundcloud Developers](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/sdks)

First post here, hope this can help someone!

Comment: Thanks for posting. Seems like an easy solution. Cheers!